# why is the following code wrong? 5

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string s= sum("jfjf");

    }


     void sum(string xx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xx);

    }
}
```

Comment: What "is wrong" with it? (There are multiple compiler errors, one is `void` methods *have no return value* and thus *cannot be used in expressions*, but please *read the error* and include such error message/symptoms *verbatim* in your post.)

Answer (score 3):

Your method returns `void` which means **nothing**, but you are trying to assign it to a string.

Either change your method definition like this:

```
static string sum(string xx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xx);
    return xx;
}
```

or don't try to assign it,just call the method:

```
sum("jfjf");
```

You should make it static too because your `Main` method is static.You can't call a **non-static** method inside of a **static** context.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call an instance method from a static method which is not valid. Also you have to return a string from the method since the caller is expecting it.

Change it to this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string s= sum("jfjf");

    }


    static string sum(string xx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xx);
        return xx;

    }
}
```

Comment: static string sum(string xx)